# How to use Global Varabile in Aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say I have a global class:

```
 static class GlobalOfficeSetting 
    {
        public static bool PatientRegistation_DialogOnly = true;

    }
```

Or let's say if I store the global variable in below instead:

```
Application("PatientRegistation_DialogOnly") = true
```

Then how will I able to call them out in aspx?
Because I want to use that as a global setting for all users to on/off display some stuff/functionality in aspx page.

Thanks in advance,
King

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<%= GlobalOfficeSetting.PatientRegistation_DialogOnly %> should work.

Comment: I tried that before, it said: Compiler Error Message: CS0122: 'ParadigmMobileAspWebForm.GlobalOfficeSetting' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Answer (score 2):

In the web form code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool dialogOnly = GlobalOfficeSetting.PatientRegistation_DialogOnly;
    // TODO: use the value
}
```

or if you decide to use the [Application state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool dialogOnly = (bool)Application["PatientRegistation_DialogOnly"];
    // TODO: use the value
}
```

and in the webform itself:

```
<%= GlobalOfficeSetting.PatientRegistation_DialogOnly %>
```

or:

```
<%= (bool)Application["PatientRegistation_DialogOnly"] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a setting that doesn't change very often, then store it in your web.config file in the settings section.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="PatientRegistation_DialogOnly" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

and in your code:

```
bool setting = (bool)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PatientRegistation_DialogOnly"];
```